# Errors 403 and 23 in Google Analytics Dashboard on WP

Tags: android, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm using a Google Analytics Dashboard for WP plugin developed by Alin Marcu. For past 12 hours I keep receiving error 403 and 23 messages saying service is not available in my country (Belgium).  It's appearing in Chrome Browser, even in incognito.  Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Here is the message in Errors & Debug section of plugin:
Last Error: 2015-11-11 12:37:46: (403) Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A101456711&start-date=today&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Ahour&quotaUser=u1s1p101456711: (403) This service is not available from your country

Comment: Maybe [this site](https://deconf.com/error-codes-in-google-analytics-dashboard-for-wordpress/) can be helpful.

Comment: Hello Augustin, I had seen this site but it does not help.  Thanks. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have been working with GA Api for some years in projects across Europe. Belgium is a country where I haven't work already, but I can't imagine that Belgium laws block Google or its services. Even in the law-friendly Germany, where I am actually located, Google and its APIs work without problem, and I have already experience in working with Italy, France, Spain, Portugal, Netherland, Poland, Great Britain and Czech Republic. If your hosting is located in China or North Korea I could understand the 403 Error... I would call a local representative of Google. They are generally really nice.